# VS Code is Unable to Find My Image Assets in My Directory

Tags: python, visual-studio, tkinter, visual-studio-code, pycharm

**Hey there, appreciate you stopping by!**

I've got an issue with VS Code. I am trying to make the jump from PyCharm to VS Code so I could use their plugins, however, when I tried running my code in VS Studio (That used to work perfectly fine in Pycharm), I encounter an error.

That error being that Vs Studio code, for some reason, is unable to find the images I stored in my directory. below is all relevant code as well as the error message found.

```
# Importing relevant modules
import tkinter as tk
import sqlite3
from tkinter import messagebox
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

# Class for the Main Window
class masterWindow:
    # Function for initialising the Master Window
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.master)
        self.master.title("HealthSync")
        self.master.geometry("500x500")
        self.master.iconbitmap("Assets/PLACEHOLDER_LOGO.ico")   #<----------------------------
        self.master.resizable(width=False, height=False)
        self.app_Logo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("Assets/PLACEHOLDER_LOGO.png"))  #<-----
        self.logo_Label = tk.Label(image=self.app_Logo)
        self.logo_Label.pack()
```

Error message:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/Python_Projects/TKinter Practise/(GROUP 4) 1191102618_Registration.py", line 150, in <module>
    main()
  File "c:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/Python_Projects/TKinter Practise/(GROUP 4) 1191102618_Registration.py", line 146, in main
    app = masterWindow(root)
  File "c:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/Python_Projects/TKinter Practise/(GROUP 4) 1191102618_Registration.py", line 15, in __init__
    self.master.iconbitmap("Assets/PLACEHOLDER_LOGO.ico")
  File "C:\python\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1865, in wm_iconbitmap
    return self.tk.call('wm', 'iconbitmap', self._w, bitmap)
_tkinter.TclError: bitmap "Assets/PLACEHOLDER_LOGO.ico" not defined  #<-----------------------
PS C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects>
```

Please note that the assets are in the directory folder written and that it displays perfectly well on PyCharm. This is a straight-up one-to-one code from my Pycharm to my VS Code.

Once again, I appreciate you stopping by and thank you for any assistance. Please message below regarding any clarifications needed, but do keep in mind I am a programming student and in no way an industry professional just yet

Comment: Is the file properly formatted, the ico? Take a look [here](https://github.com/NetroScript/Graveyard-Keeper-Savefile-Editor/issues/43)

Comment: @Haqeem Wan Usually, the script cannot find the file or the picture because the path cannot be found, and VSCode searches for the picture from the root folder of the project by default, so we can enter the path to help it find it. (From the root folder to the folder where the picture is located). And you also could try to use the absolute path of the picture directly.